# Exibir div de acordo com a nota

Tags: jquery

Esse script funciona da seguinte forma: se um dos 3 *dropdowns* tiverem nota menor que 8, ele mostrará o conteúdo de uma `div` oculta.

Funciona da seguinte forma:

- 1º *dropdown* tiver nota <= 8  // Mostra a `div`
- 2º *dropdown* tiver nota <= 8  // Como 1º já é a baixo mantém a `div` a mostra.

Agora aqui é a condição com problema:

- 3º *dropdown* tiver nota acima >= 8 // ele oculta a div , e não pode pois já existe nota abaixo de 8 entre os três *dropdowns*.

Resumindo: Se algum dos 3 *dropdowns* forem menor que 8: mostrar a `div`.

```js
var Privileges = jQuery('#privileges1');
var select = this.value;
Privileges.change(function() {
  if (parseInt($(this).val()) < 8) {
    $('.resources').show();
  } else {
    $('.resources').hide();
  }
});


var Privileges = jQuery('#privileges2');
var select = this.value;
Privileges.change(function() {
  if (parseInt($(this).val()) < 8) {
    $('.resources').show();
  } else {
    $('.resources').hide();
  }
});


var Privileges = jQuery('#privileges3');
var select = this.value;
Privileges.change(function() {
  if (parseInt($(this).val()) < 8) {
    $('.resources').show();
  } else {
    $('.resources').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="pes21" id="privileges1" class="" onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<select name="pes22" id="privileges2" class="" onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<select name="pes23" id="privileges3" class="" onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div class="resources" style=" display: none;">
  <p>Ola texto</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fabioo7/710uh90x/

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma solução bonita pois ela esta sendo forçada a trabalhar com 3 valores:

```
$('#privileges1').change(function(){validaValor()});
$('#privileges2').change(function(){validaValor()});
$('#privileges3').change(function(){validaValor()});

function validaValor() {
  x = parseInt($('#privileges1').val());
  y = parseInt($('#privileges2').val());
  z = parseInt($('#privileges3').val());

  if((x + y + z) < 24) { // 8 + 8 + 8
    $('.resources').show();
  } else {
    $('.resources').hide();
  }
}
```

Seu código não estava funcionando porque ele estava considerando somente o valor de cada select e não o valor das três.

**EDIÇÃO**

Fabio Henrique, realmente não previ essa situação então sugiro uma outra solução, que também não é bonita pois força o uso de uma quantidade X de objetos:

```
$('#privileges1').change(function(){validaValor()});
$('#privileges2').change(function(){validaValor()});
$('#privileges3').change(function(){validaValor()});

function validaValor() {
  x = parseInt($('#privileges1').val());
  y = parseInt($('#privileges2').val());
  z = parseInt($('#privileges3').val());

  if(x < 8 || y < 8 || z < 8) {
    $('.resources').show();
  } else {
    $('.resources').hide();
  }
}
```

Caso você consiga uma outra solução, por favor responda sua própria pergunta, esse problema me parece bem interessante para ser resolvido de uma maneira mais genérica e capaz de lidar com N objetos dinamicamente, vou continuar em busca de uma solução melhor.

Comment: Gerep... E isso mesmo... só que tem algum bugsinho, se coloco  9 9 10 e mudo a pra  7 9 10 as vezes não aparece a div